# In Metal Gear Solid, why did Foxhound need Snake?

Tags: metal-gear-solid

Metal Gear Solid is a tactical stealth-ops game wrapped in an enigmatic nuclear-themed storyline.  One part of that storyline has always bugged me.

Halfway through the game, it comes to light that, in order to launch the nuclear missiles on Rex, the terrorists need either two detonation codes, or three card keys.  They lose the ability to use the codes, and so are dependent on finding the card keys.

And for some reason, they need to let a stealth operative into the military complex they took over so that *he* can find it for them.

This doesn't exactly make sense to me - why would Foxhound need to bring in someone who knows less about the military complex than they do?  Why would they need him to find the keycard, when they could just search the base themselves?

Yes, it's being held by Meryl when they found her, but they had **her** in captivity until Snake arrived.  Had they just done a better job of searching their prisoners, they would've found the keycard no problem.  She can't even resist their psychic's mind control, so he could've just found out if she knew where it was, and taken it from her.

Where, in all of this, is it necessary for them to bring in Snake to find the keycard for them?

Note that while a full explanation of how things went down is fine, all I'm really looking for is Foxhound's *original* plan, and how it required Snake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After researching for a bit, I found this very interesting forum post which pretty much explains why they needed snake. Please note that this is fan speculation (an official explanation might not even exist). Prepare for a wall of text.

> FOXHOUND knew about PAL, the issue was finding the keys. They didn't know about the shape memory aspects. Baker had talked under duress however, and so Liquid could've most likely coerced Baker into opening his private files, should the need become apparent. Point is, Liquid had options.
>
> But he decided to play chess, using Snake as a pawn, to see if Snake knew something useful. Something that could speed up the process of reacquiring nuclear launch capability. It was why he placed Octopus in the cells in the first place rather than simply have his unit hunt Snake from Minute One. Liquid did intend to kill Snake, as proved by the presence of the soldiers sent to kill him immediately after he met Octopus/DARPA Chief in the cell, but what was a total surprise to everyone was FOXDIE. Snake, in moving through the facility and inadvertantly killing Baker, suddenly became the only option in locating PAL and its instructive use.
>
> To that end, Liquid had to keep Snake alive and ignorant. Ignorant of the larger issue, that FOXHOUND couldn't launch, and alive so Snake could get the PAL and the info on how to use it. But Snake caused a fuckload of trouble. More trouble than he was worth. Eventually, Liquid probably felt he had no other choice but to kill off Snake, and track down Emmerich, who he could then use to get the necessary information. See, once Meryl revealed to Snake she had the PAL key (or at least one of them, in Liquid's mind), all that was necessary was learning more about PAL. Liquid was in the know about Snake's conversations with both Hal and Meryl. He was getting a better picture of what PAL was. But it was coming at a cost.
>
> Added to things was Gray Fox, and Ocelot's subterfuge. These two things permitted Snake a great advantage. Had Ocelot not been playing Liquid, Snake would've lost the key, his life, and Emmerich would've been briefing Liquid on how to use PAL. But remember, Ocelot told Liquid that Snake 'didn't have any keys on him' which was total bullshit. Ocelot was fucking around because his goal was to ensure that no actual nuclear launch occurred.
>
> Liquid was genuinely trying to off Snake by the time Snake escaped from his cell. Up until then, he was monitoring Snake's movements, keeping things plausibly intense, and would capture him when necessary. Liquid knew what Snake was capable of, at least on paper, and also knew if he didn't provide a sufficient battleground, Snake would eventually suspect the deeper plan. But Liquid realized he'd need to know how powerful Snake was in order to control him effectively during this fact finding manipulation. So he used FOXHOUND, and permitted them to engage and assess Snake's abilities. Doing so also smoked out a few unknowns, like Gray Fox.
>
> Liquid made a fatal error in not killing Snake immediately. FOXDIE really put a damper on his day. Had Snake died right away, I'm thinking Ocelot might've been the one to neutralize FOXHOUND en masse by the time Liquid finally did figure out the PAL system.

You can find the thread [here](http://mgsforums.com/topic/7508810/1/)

And now to **the original plan**:

FOXHOUND originally did not need Snake. They planed to get the 2 codes from the DARPA Chief Donald Anderson and Arms Tech President Kenneth Baker. They had 2 people that were perfect for this job - Revolver Ocelot (torturer) and Psycho Mantis (mind reading/control). Too bad that Ocelot killed Donald Anderson before he could get his code, so they had to think of another plan.

Comment: While this probably explains the whole thing very well, I think it should be pointed out that it's not an official explanation (because one most likely doesn't exist), but rather a (pretty convincing) fan speculation of why they needed Snake.

Comment: @Chippies - Yes, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: It's also actually considerably more than what I was asking for - which is fine, but I do feel I should point out (and will add it to my question) that all I really am interested in is Foxhound's *original* plan, not how badly it got screwed up.

Comment: Foxhound's original plan was to use the detonation codes..

Comment: @Zibbobz - added that bit to my answer. It's not that complicated.

Comment: Not quite what I meant - not their original plans before they needed snake, their original plans *for* Snake, before he mucked things up.  You already included that in the answer, I was just pointing out that my question is a lot simpler than this forum post makes it out to be.